# Call start and end function in each operation in a wcf-service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service with a lot of operations.
For each operation, I would like to execute a function when the method starts and ends (for logging).

For example:

```
public Person FindPerson(string name)
{
    Log("Start",...);

    ...

    Log("Stop",...);
}
```

Is there a way that this can be implemented for all of the methods in the wcf-service?
Maybe in a beforeStart/afterEnd-event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx. You're interested in `IOperationInvoker` interface. WCF is quite extensible and quite complicated too but OperationInvoker should meet your requirements. If you're looking for more generic approach consider Interception in your DI Container (if you're using one) or think about adding AOP capabilities through specialized framework, ie. [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/download).

Answer (score 1):

Empi beat me to it, but I'll post it anyway :)

Logging is typical candidate for [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

You can use one of many dependency injection containers to take care of instantiating your services and application of runtime aspects.

Or you can use [postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com) and apply logging aspects to your service implementation. See [example](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging) to get started. Your code would then look like following:

```
[Trace]
public person FindPerson(string name)
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how we are doing it, maybe that is an option for you.
We are using a AOP style attribute for this, but with a self-developed code (so no postsharp, ...). PostSharp would work as well.

And then we have a unit test which checks every method (reflection) to verify that the attribute has been added.

We did it this way, because I don't want to use WCF for logging, as the attribute solution is more generic so we can utilize elsewhere.